# How to set "Types" in Google Place PlacePicker in Android?

Tags: android, location, google-places-api

In the new google places API, they come with a new feature called PlacePicker. It's a simple activity to select a place of the list/map of places they have.

In the Places API we can give a types list, to receive only places of those specific types.

I'm building an app that uses only "establishment" places.

But this activity shows all the places, including a lot of places that i do not need (libraries, schools, gas ...)

**There is a way to set the types of the PlacePicker?**

Reading the API docs doesn't say nothing about.

Answer (score 5):

Currently it seems not to be possible. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8484), however. Please star it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently right now, android have documentation to do some filtering using AutocompleteFilter class. The documentation of [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete)

example of usage :

```
//set boundary on build place picker fragment
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
builder.setLatLngBounds(bounds);

 //set filter type by country 'malaysia'
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
    .setTypeFilter(1013) //set point of interest
    .setCountry("MY")
    .build();

try {
    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
        .setFilter(typeFilter)
        .build(MainActivity.this);

    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);        
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
}
```