# How can I limit the GMSPlacePicker to only specified place type(s)?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'd like to use the Google Places API for iOS [place picker](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker), but it displays places of all types in the map. I'd to be able to supply a set of [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) to limit the types of place that the user can select from.

Is this possible? The [Google Places web service api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) allows for a ***type*** parameter to limit results. Is there any plan to support this in the iOS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the moment, the [Place Picker API](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker) doesn't have the feature to filter the *Place Types* you want to be returned. There is actually an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8484) about it.

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32562382/6124253

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268633/6124253